# js-yaml issue with tags

Tags: node.js, yaml

I am currently trying to edit 2 messages in a yaml file but js-yaml does not seem to understand what to do with what I think is a tag on the first line:

```
--- !Status
Default:
    Description:
        - |-
            Message1
            Message2
Samples:
    Multiple: false
    DynamicPlayers: false
Unknown:
    PlayerName: player
    PlayerCount: '???'
Favicon:
    Timeout: 10s
    RecursiveFolderSearch: false
    ResizeStrategy: SCALE
```

When I safeload the document I get: `YAMLException: unknown tag !<!Status> at line 17, column 1:` Is there any way for me to just let it ignore the tag or is there a different way around this problem? I'm not able to remove the tag because that would stop the program from reading the config file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at [`examples/custom_types.js`](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml/blob/f6bafed1c4d82e80ab3fc3a71a5af63308f54b2f/examples/custom_types.js) in the js-yaml repo. The solution is to create a new `jsyaml.Type` that tells js-yaml to treat `!Status` values as mappings, like so:

```
let StatusYamlType = new jsyaml.Type('!Status', { kind: 'mapping' });
```

Then you need to create a new Schema that includes the `StatusYamlType` type:

```
let STATUS_SCHEMA = jsyaml.Schema.create([ StatusYamlType ]);
```

Finally, pass the new `STATUS_SCHEMA` to `jsyaml.safeLoad` via the `schema` option:

```
jsyaml.safeLoad(doc, { schema: STATUS_SCHEMA });
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there's a way to make js-yaml ignore all tags, so if you encounter others you'll have to define Types for them as well.

If you also want to *write* YAML files with the `!Status` tag then you'll have to actually define a Status prototype and supply the `construct` and `instanceOf` options to the `jsyaml.Type` constructor [as in the example](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml/blob/f6bafed1c4d82e80ab3fc3a71a5af63308f54b2f/examples/custom_types.js#L37-L63). A very basic implementation looks like this:

```
function Status(data) {
  Object.assign(this, data);
}

let StatusYamlType = new jsyaml.Type('!Status', {
  kind: 'mapping',
  instanceOf: Status,
  construct: data => new Status(data),
});
```

Then you pass the schema to `jsyaml.safeDump` just like you did to `safeLoad`:

```
jsyaml.safeDump(result, { schema: STATUS_SCHEMA })
```

Take a look at the below snippet to see it in action.

```js
let doc = `--- !Status
Default:
    Description:
        - |-
            Message1
            Message2
# ...
`;

function Status(data) {
  Object.assign(this, data);
}

let StatusYamlType = new jsyaml.Type('!Status', {
  kind: 'mapping',
  instanceOf: Status,
  construct: data => new Status(data),
});

let STATUS_SCHEMA = jsyaml.Schema.create([ StatusYamlType ]);

let result = jsyaml.safeLoad(doc, { schema: STATUS_SCHEMA });
console.log(result.constructor.name, result);

console.log(jsyaml.safeDump(result, { schema: STATUS_SCHEMA }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-yaml/3.7.0/js-yaml.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, the `safeDump` output uses a slightly different tag syntax than your original input (`!<!Status>` rather than `--- !Status`), but in this context they are equivalent and YAML parsers should treat them as such.

Comment: jsyaml.safeDump(result, { schema: STATUS_SCHEMA }) worked for me to read !include from existing yaml     -thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with an AWS Cloud Formation Template when editing it in Visual Studio Code.

I found that within the user settings if I added the following lines of code to my user-settings.json, it allowed for the tags.

```
    "yaml.customTags": [
        "!Equals sequence",
        "!FindInMap sequence",
        "!GetAtt",
        "!GetAZs",
        "!ImportValue",
        "!Join sequence",
        "!Ref",
        "!Select sequence",
        "!Split sequence",
        "!Sub"
    ]
```

Yours would follow the same contruct. `"!Status sequence"`

This tells the YAML configuration exactly what to expect.

Comment: Where would I find user-settings.json?

Comment: Mac: Code > Preferences > Settings... There is a `{}` at the top right-hand corner of the page, this will bring you to the settings as JSON. Add this block and save your changes. I would imagine the Windows experience is similar, except for the menu bar at the top. I would check under Edit > Preferences.

Comment: Of VSCode?  I was looking to use jsyaml on the command line to read a Cloud Formation Template.  Thanks